# How to return only the highest element from two distinct lists only if their product is palindromic?

Tags: python

I am a beginner learning Python and working thru the challenges found in Project Euler. I was attempting question number 4, but I am having trouble adjusting my script.

Here is the question:

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome
> made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit
> numbers.

I constructed the following code:

```
lst1 = list(range(1,100))
lst2 = list(range(1,100))

def palindrome(a,b):
    for i in a:
        for i2 in b:
            z = i * i2
            if str(z)[::] == str(z)[::-1]:
                print("\n")
                
                # Print if palindromic and only highest value from lst1 and lst2
                if max(str(i) and max(str(i2))):
                    print(f"lst1 value: {str(i):>5}")
                    print(f"lst1 value: {str(i2):>5}")
                    print(f"Product = {str(z):>7}")
```

The script I created has helped me solve 50% of the problem. I noticed I am missing some condition that only filters on the highest elements in both lst1 and lst2, and returns only the highest elements when their product is palindromic. If I run the script above, I have to scroll to the very bottom to find 91 and 99. This is not efficient at all, especially when  I increase the range up to 1000.

How can I fix my script?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to solve the challenge. Below is the solution I used:

```
lst1 = list(range(1,1000))
lst2 = list(range(1,1000))

def palindrome(a,b):
    for i in a:
        for i2 in b:
            z = i * i2
            if str(z)[::] == str(z)[::-1]:
                
                while i > 900 and i2 > 900:
                    print(f"lst1 value: {str(i):>5}")
                    print(f"lst1 value: {str(i2):>5}")
                    print(f"Product = {str(z):>7}")
                    print("\n")
                    break
```

If you have another more efficient solution, please share as I am curious of others ways to solve this challenge.

Comment: Keep track of the largest palindrome in the loop, and print it when the loop is _finished_.

Comment: It might also be more efficient to make the ranges be 100-1  instead of 1-100, so you're checking the largest values _first_.

Comment: How can I keep track of the largest palindrome? Do I do this with a while loop?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get result like this:

```
list=[]
for i in range(100,999):
  for j in range(100,999):
    pro=i*j
    if str(pro)==str(pro)[::-1]:
        list.append(pro)
print(max(list))
```

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
print(max([i*j for i in range(900,1000) for j in range(900,1000) if str(i*j) == str(i*j)[::-1]]))
```

result:

```
906609
```